# How to create a method to which I could either pass function or a functor?

Tags: c++, function, functor

Basically, I am implementing a container class. I need to create a method which sorts the data according to the comparator function/functor which must be passed with the sort request. Since declaration and definition of the method are in different files(.h and .cpp) using templates becomes a problem (and I don't have much experience using them). In other words, I want to make a method:

```
void sort(function/functor f);
```

and I don't know how to define the function. So, is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Using templates doesn't become a problem - just remember that they (usually) need to be defined in a header. There are type-erasing alternatives (like `std::function`), if you really want to avoid templates for some reason, and don't mind the extra run-time costs.

Comment: How big is the body of your `sort` function?  Is there any chance you can expose iterator-based access to your container?

Comment: Basically, it will just delegate a call to the standard sort function.

Comment: @user1242967 then why put its body in the `.cpp` file instead of the header?  That will have performance implications in practice.  `std::sort` is fast because it gets compiled with full knowledge of the comparator, and crossing compilation units tends to erase that knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the signature of the function/functor to be passed[*], you can use `std::function`. Or `boost::function` if you don't have C++11. So for a comparator it would be:

```
void sort(std::function<bool(const Element&, const Element&)> f);
```

where `Element` is the type of the elements of the container.

Failing that you could define a class with a `virtual` compare function, and allow callers to derive from it with their own class. It's more work for callers, but that's exactly what `std::function` provides: a way for callers to not have to do that.

Two warnings:

- make sure there's really a good reason for the implementation of your container not to be in the header file. All of the standard containers are implemented in header files, and that mostly works OK.
- make sure there's really a good reason for you to implement a `sort` function. Standard containers only have `sort` functions where `std::sort` doesn't work: `std::list` and `std::forward_list`.

[*] Actually `std::function` doesn't require the exact same signature. You just say the types you want to call it with and the type you want to convert the return value to. So if you call it with two `int`s and the caller provides a function that takes two `long`s, then that's fine. The arguments are converted just like the function call would without any `std::function`.

Comment: Even if you don't know the signature, you know how it will be called in the body of your function.  `std::function` (and I assume `boost::`) will type erase anything *compatible* with the signature it declares.

Answer (score 2):

This is generally done with templates. Like this:

```
#include <iostream> // For example output only.

template <typename F>
void sort(F&& pred) {
    pred(123);
}

void normal_func(int v) {
    std::cout << "normal_func(" << v << ")\n";
}

struct my_pred {
    void operator()(int v) const {
        std::cout << "my_pred(" << v << ")\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    sort([](int v) { std::cout << "Called lambda func with " << v << '\n'; });
    sort(normal_func);
    sort(my_pred());
}
```

If, however, templates cannot be used, then your best bet would be to use polymorphic function wrapper like [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (or [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/function.html), or you can write your own simple version).

Alternatively, you can use a hardcore C-style regular function along with a void pointer where user can save their context. For example, like [`qsort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort). Though I'd try not to go there if possible.

Here is an example using `std::function`:

```
#include <iostream> // For example output only.
#include <functional> // For std::function.

void sort(const std::function<void(int)>& pred) {
    pred(123);
}

void normal_func(int v) {
    std::cout << "normal_func(" << v << ")\n";
}

struct my_pred {
    void operator()(int v) const {
        std::cout << "my_pred(" << v << ")\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    sort([](int v) { std::cout << "Called lambda func with " << v << '\n'; });
    sort(normal_func);
    sort(my_pred());
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But does the solution with templates work in my case? I only have the declaration of sort in header file, .cpp file contains the implementation. As far as I know, the code wouldn't compile in my case.

Comment: @user1242967: That's why I have provided an example using `std::function` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::function` as suggested in Steve Jessop's answer but in this case I think you should consider making your sort function a template function as in Vlad's answer. A sort function has to call the comparator many times and there will be noticeable overhead to using `std::function` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use a template:

```
  class C
  {
      template<typename T>
      void sort(T func)
      {
            func(12,45);   // Will compile as long as your function/functor
      }                    // Can take two integers as parameters.
  };                       // NOTE: or integers can be converted into your parameters.
```

If you want to specify using old C notation.

```
  typedef void (*FUNC_TYPE)(int, int);  // declares a function pointer type.
                                        // returns void takes two integers.
  class C
  {
      void sort(FUNC_TYPE func)
      {
          func(12,45);                      // Compiles only if the function
      }                                     // matches the exact type.
  };
```

The C++11 way

```
  class C
  {
      void sort(std::function<void(int,int)> func)
      {
          func(12,45);                     // Will match any func/functor that
                                           // will return a void and takes two
      }                                    // integers.
  };
```

Comment: Of course, the "C" way only works with functions, not callable class objects, so that doesn't apply to this question.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I disagree. He needs a function/functor that will allow him to sort elements (so he only needs to know the element types). That works fine with C style function (though that is not the way I would go). Did I miss something more subtle?

Comment: @LokiAstari: I think the intention of the questioner is that the caller should be free to choose whether to pass a function or a(nother) functor. Not that the author of the container restricts it to just functions.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I agree that's what he wants. I just wanted to lay out all the alternatives for defining callbacks.